# Sorting a file numerically

Tags: python, file

I am  new to python and trying to create a maths quiz program towards the end of the program I want to be able to print all the results in the file ( stored in the variable Reverseinfo) in numerical order. This doesn't seem to work , regardless of if I use the .sort function or the sorted() function. Any help would be appreciated, thanks

ReverseInfo already has scores and names put into the file

```
ReverseInfo= (score + (" ") + Name)

ClassANum=open("Class A Results High to Low.txt","a")
    ClassANum.write(ReverseInfo)
    ClassANum.write(" \n")
    ClassANum.close()

ClassBNum=open("Class B Results High to Low.txt","a")
    ClassBNum.write(ReverseInfo)
    ClassBNum.write(" \n")
    ClassBNum.close()

ClassCNum=open("Class C Results High to Low.txt","a")
    ClassCNum.write(ReverseInfo)
    ClassCNum.write(" \n")
    ClassCNum.close()


        if Viewscores=="Y":
            Classresults=input("Which Class would you like to see the results of?")

        if Classresults=="A":
            ClassA=open("Class A Results.txt","r")
            Class=ClassA
            alphabet=ClassA.readlines()
            for line in sorted(alphabet):
                print(line)

        elif Classresults=="B":
            ClassB=open("Class B Results.txt","r")
            Class=ClassB
            alphabet=ClassB.readlines()
            for line in sorted(alphabet):
                print(line)

        elif Classresults=="C":
            ClassC=open("Class C Results.txt","r")
            Class=ClassC
            alphabet=ClassC.readlines()
            for line in sorted(alphabet):
                print(line)

        else:
            print ("That is not valid")

        Numerical=input(" Do you want to see the results alphabetically?")

        if Numerical=="Y":
            NumClassresults=input("Which Class would you like to see the results of?")

        if NumClassresults=="A":
            ClassA=open("Class A Results High to Low.txt","r")
            Class=ClassA
            Hightolow=ClassA.readlines()
            for line in sorted(Hightolow):
                print(line)

        elif NumClassresults=="B":
            ClassA=open("Class B Results High to Low.txt","r")
            Class=ClassB
            Hightolow=ClassB.readlines()
            for line in sorted(Hightolow):
                print(line)

        if NumClassresults=="C":
            ClassA=open("Class C Results High to Low.txt","r")
            Class=ClassC
            Hightolow=ClassC.readlines()
            for line in sorted(Hightolow):
                print(line)
```

the data stored in Class A is: 10 Jamie 
8 Jamie 
8 Peter 
10 Ham 
4 Jack 
10 Joseph 
9 jamie 
9 Yuan 
9 Bob 
10 John 
6 Nash 
8 John 
10 josh 
10 Honey

there is currently nothing stored in Class b file 
finally in class c:
9 jamie

9 Yuan

9 Bob

8 Peter

8 Jamie

4 Jack

10 Joseph

10 John

10 Jamie

10 Ham

Comment: You can not sort a file. You can create file, read from file, write to file, lock file, delete file. That's all you can do with a file. You can sort some items in the memory though and those items can be deserialized from file and sorted result can be serialized to file. Try to decouple your objective to small tasks.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the question, can you post a smaller chunk with your input and expected output. I believe your issue is because you're trying to sort strings instead of sorting results by int score

Comment: To alexander Trakhimenok, should I try to convert my file into a list?

Comment: To BAH , how would I just sort the integers of the file?

Comment: To jamieT-G, use @username to ping someone.

Answer (score 0):

Try below (assuming your file looks like `Name 100` with many rows)

```
with open("Class C Results High to Low.txt","r") as f:
    lines = [(int(line.split(" ")[0]), line.split(" ")[1]) for line in f.readlines()]
    for l in sorted(lines, key=lambda score_name: score_name[0]):
        print l
```

Please let me know if there are any syntax errors (leave a comment), I couldn't test this - on the phone at the moment.

Comment: When I tried to use your solution I got this error:                                 raceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/Maths quiz new.1.py", line 175, in <module>
    lines = [(int(score), name) for line in f.readlines() for (name, score) in line.split(" ")]
  File "C:/Python34/Maths quiz new.1.py", line 175, in <listcomp>
    lines = [(int(score), name) for line in f.readlines() for (name, score) in line.split(" ")]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'i'

Comment: add your file to the question. I need to see the contents of your scores file (Class C Results High to Low.txt)

Comment: this is what I saw in the interpreter: 9 jamie 

9 Yuan 

9 Bob 

8 Peter 

8 Jamie 

4 Jack 

10 Joseph 

10 John 

10 Jamie 

10 Ham

Comment: this is the error I got:    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/Maths quiz new.1.py", line 175, in <module>
    lines = [(int(score), name) for line in f.readlines() for (name, score) in line.split(" ")]
  File "C:/Python34/Maths quiz new.1.py", line 175, in <listcomp>
    lines = [(int(score), name) for line in f.readlines() for (name, score) in line.split(" ")]
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: I just tried the second method I received an error message :      Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/Maths quiz new.1.py", line 162, in <module>
    Hightolow = [int(x) for x in ClassA]
  File "C:/Python34/Maths quiz new.1.py", line 162, in <listcomp>
    Hightolow = [int(x) for x in ClassA]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Hi \n'

Comment: post all your txt files, the input keeps varying so the code isn't handling it.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is just lines with one integer per line, `Hightolow` will be a list of strings (that can be passed to int)

You need to pass a key function to sorted (or sort). In this case `int` does exactly what you need.

```
sorted(Hightolow, key=int)
```

ie use it in the loop like this:

```
for line in sorted(Hightolow, key=int):
```

Alternatively you can make `Hightolow` a list of ints as you read the file

```
Hightolow = [int(x) for x in ClassA]
```

Comment: the first method did not seem to work, but thanks anyway, I will try the second method, where would I implement the next bit of code?

Comment: You'd replace the line `Hightolow=ClassA.readlines()` with `Hightolow = [int(x) for x in ClassA]`